# Pyramid app with handlebar.js: I don't need a template for this view; how to disable?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, pyramid

I'm adding a page to a complex Pyramid-based app that uses Handlebar templates.

I need a file download URL that doesn't need a template, but the system is giving me a 404
code for missing template anyway.

How do I tell a view at configuration time "do not use a handlebar template with this one?"

Answer (score 1):

This was a red herring; the URL was wrong but the log file mentioned a missing template so I was focused in the wrong direction.

I had to get a custom redirection piece of code from one of the developers on this project and I have it working now.